# Accessing HTML5 Custom Data Attributes for multiple instances of webpart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, custom-attributes

I would really appreciate some guidance.  This is probably simple to some of you, but i can't figure it out.
Thanks for any input.

**THE REQUIREMENT**

I have a multi-tabbed control.  One each tab, I have a custom reportviewer control.

I have added a custom attribute to the reportviewer in the code behind called "data-report-param".

I need to access the value of custom attribute "data-report-param" on the current tab on the client-side using javascript.

I have tried several ways including the following, ***but can't get to the value that is being created in the DOM.***

**MY CODE**

```
//Attempt 1
var reportparamattribute = $('#ReportViewer1');
var reportparametervalue = reportparamattribute.getAttribute('data-report-param');

//Attempt 2
var reportparamattribute = document.getElementById('<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>');
var reportparametervalue = reportparamattribute.getAttribute('data-report-param');

//Also tried accessing the dataset
var reportparametervalue = reportparamattribute.dataset.report-param;
```

**WHAT IS BEING PRODUCED IN THE DOM**
   ('ctl00_m_g_66e41117_8ff5_4650_bf4d_7a4a25e326f3_ctl01_ReportViewer1_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" data-report-param="1068" interactivedeviceinfos="(Collection)">

('ctl00_m_g_9d6a6c3c_11d0_4e03_bbd2_b907172c437d_ctl01_ReportViewer1_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" data-report-param="1068" interactivedeviceinfos="(Collection)">

#### UPDATE- WORKING CODE BELOW

The key was passing the custom data attribute from the code behind and then accessing it in the $.cache as @popnoodles below indicated, and passing the clientID of the reportviewer into the javascript function to get to the current instance of the webpart child controls.

```
<input type="hidden" id="<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_myDataState" 
onchange="compareUnitValues(this.id, this.parentNode.id, '<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>',  '<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>', '<%= btnSendHiddenField.ClientID %>');" />

<script type ="text/javascript">
function compareUnitValues(elemt, parent, reportviewerID, value1, value2) {
  var myDataUnit = $("#" + elemt),
     parentObject = $("#" + parent),
     reportviewerObject = $("#" + reportviewerID),
     ssrs    = $("#" + value1),
     btnSend = $("#" + value2);

  var myDataUnitValue = myDataUnit.val();
  var myDataUnitJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(myDataUnitValue);
  var currentmyDataUnit = myDataUnitJSON.currentUnit.objectId;
  var sessioncurrentObjectId = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenCurrentObjectId.ClientID %>').value;
  ssrs.val(myDataUnitValue);
  var currentReportViewerParam = $("#" + reportviewerID).attr("data-report-param");

  if (currentmyDataUnit != currentReportViewerParam) {
  btnSend.trigger("click");
  }
```

}

#### FROM CODE BEHIND CREATE THE CUSTOM DATA ATTRIBUTE

```
ReportViewer1.Attributes.Add("data-report-param", parsedObjectId)
```

Comment: actually if we could see the relevant html/jsp it would help.

Comment: Your second attempt should work, if you trying to get value of custom data attribute after you actually created it. first and third attempt is wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I am struggling to understand the basics here. I thought I could access the current state of the DOM using Javascript.    The reportviewer isn't showing up in the html. The report viewer is buried in the webpart in the html. <div WebPartID="9d6a6c3c-11d0-4e03-bbd2-b907172c437d"

Comment: @Givi.  Thanks.  I will retry attempt 2

Comment: @Frank.  Thanks Frank.  I'm not sure what else to provide.  As I mention, the report viewer attributes are hidden inside the webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute` will only give you the value  that was in the generated or modified HTML **not** what is in the DOM. The data method **never** updates the HTML.

jQuery creates an empty object `$.cache`, which is used to store the values you set via the data method. Each DOM element you add data to is assigned a unique ID which is used as a key in the `$.cache` object.

Setting

```
$('#ReportViewer1').data('report-param', 1234);
```

Getting

```
var id = $('#ReportViewer1').data('report-param');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I guess I don't understand some basic concepts here.  If I run the page and then view the DOM using the developer tools, and the data-report-param is there, can I not get to it?  It isn't rendered in the html, it is buried inside the webpart.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: data-report-param is an attribute. It's used once on page load and never again. Looking at it by inspecting the HTML won't do you any favours. Type `$('#ReportViewer1').data('report-param');` into the console. That will give you want you want

Comment: I get undefined even though the DOM output (above) shows a data-report-param value for each instance of the reportviewer.  Thanks for your patience, but any guess what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The data isn't in the DOM! It's in an object $.cache, you cannot view it by inspecting the page.

Comment: Thanks. I apologize if I am not using the correct terms.  It is present in this output, I guess this is the cache you are referring to.  I should be able to access this correct? You can see three instances of the reportviewer all with the value 1068 in the custom data field data-report-param.  Thanks for your help and patience, I am not trying to be dense, I just haven't worked on the front end much.  Still learning.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9305638/DOM.txt

Comment: I view this by right clicking and 'inspecting element' in firefox and viewing the inspector window.

Comment: How many times do I need to tell you **the attribute "data-report-param" (in the HTML which is what you're looking at) is never updated, the data is stored in an object in javascript, you HAVE to use the jQuery .data() method**

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  Sorry it took a minute for me to catch on.  I posted my working code above.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery why not just:

```
$("#reportviewer1").data('report-param');
```

Comment: Thanks Frank.  That's the thing.  It doesn't return anything.

Comment: can you 'view source' on the page to see what the element looks like?

Comment: Thanks Frank.   If I run the page and then view the DOM using the developer tools, and the data-report-param is there, but I can not get to it. It isn't rendered in the html, it is buried inside the webpart. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I posted the full page source here on dropbox. You can see 3 instances of the webpart. There is a report veiwer fully rendered on each. I also attached a screenshot. page source https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9305638/page%20source.txt         screeshot https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9305638/screenshot%20of%20webpart.png

Comment: I also put the full output of the DOM. You can see the data-report-param with a value of 1068   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9305638/DOM.txt

Comment: This is the state of the page before I try to get the "1068" value out of the data-report-param.

Comment: According to that source you should be getting: `$("#ctl00_m_g_66e41117_8ff5_4650_bf4d_7a4a25e326f3_ctl01_ReportViewer1").data('report-param');`

Comment: I can get to the value by typing this into the web concloe. $("#ctl00_m_g_9d6a6c3c_11d0_4e03_bbd2_b907172c437d_ctl01_ReportViewer1").attr('data-report-param');  Now I just need to figure out how to get to the current instance of the reportviewer as there are 3 of them, one on each tab.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: yeah I'm sure that that long string is something like a uuid. good luck. If I answered your question be sure click the check next to my answer